# regex - block whitespaces in url

Tags: regex, url, whitespace

I'm using a regular expression to match Facebook url.

```
((http|https)://)?(www[.])?facebook.com/.+
```

It accepts:

> facebook.com/xxxxx 
> [www.facebook.com/xxxxx](http://www.facebook.com/xxxxx) 
> http://facebook.com/xxxxx 
> https://facebook.com/xxxxx

But it still accepts whitespaces after /:

> facebook.com/(spaces there)

**How can I prevent it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the pattern by making the s optional in https using a quesion mark,  and use `\S+` to match 1 or more non whitespace characters instead of `.+` which can also match spaces.

```
(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com/\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6TU9LH/1)

Comment: Thanks! Working very well now :D